# How to add redirects to pages with a query string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I may be wrong in this but i'm seeing loads of answers for appending to a query string when using .htaccess for redirects but wondered if there was a clear way of achieving the following:

```
RewriteRule ^old-webpage/$ http://newwebsite.com/intro?redirect=oldsite [R=301,L]
```

So the old website doesn't have query strings and i'd like to be able to redirect people to the new site with a query string in place so I can adjust a few things and show a message.

This will work in redirecting, however now I'm getting the domain:

`http://newwebsite.com/intro?redirect=oldsiteoldweb-page/`

so is there something missing in the Rewrite rules that stops the old-webpage being concatenated to the query string after it's redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above example didn´t work for my System so I suggest you following working conditions & rules:

**Option 1 - dynamic param**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/intro?redirect=%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

**Version 2 - static parameter**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/intro?redirect=oldsite [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks (only just seen your reply) this worked I had something to this affect in the end but giving you the tick for ref